# link from index to folder works locally but not on server

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have had a look but I can't figure out what causes my issue. The problem is following:

I have a page that I've developed locally and all works fine. Now I have uploaded everything to my public_html and the index.html, CSS and JS works fine, but it doesn't show any images or fonts.

The file structure is like this:

index.html

- css/style.min.css
  css/animations.css
- js/jquery.min.js
  js/main.min.js
- fonts/micon/css/micon.min.css
- img/hakn-min.jpg etc

As far I understand the links should look the same, and they do as seen from my 'head' for example:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="fonts/micon/css/micon.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/animations.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.min.css">
```

From my understanding, if the stylesheets are working, the fonts should as well. Anyone who can help me get my head around this?

Edit: the images from the CSS works fine.

Thanks,

Håkan

Comment: how have you linked your  images ? also share link

Comment: link: azzax.net/portfolio

Comment: example of img in index.

    ' <div id="mlslp" class="thumb animated fadeIn slowest">
                    <img src="img/portfolio/thumbnails/mlslp-min.jpg" alt="Mondragon Lingua Skype Lesson Plan">
                    <i class="mi mi-OpenInNewWindow"></i>
                </div>'

Comment: check the permission on these folders and files on your server..

Comment: Indeed, give the correct permissions with `chmod 777`

Comment: Thanks. Is there a easy way to change the permissions on a server?

Comment: If you have FTP access, you can open a connection with filezilla or whatever client you use. Right click on the folder or image, then click permissions -> check `read`, `write` and `execute`

Comment: I've been trying to set it up in FireFTP now, but I can't get access. Do you know how to do it with the command line?

Comment: Which hosting do you use? Windows or Apache?

Comment: I'm on Linux. The hosting I'm using are using Apache and Nginx

Comment: I'm trying to set up FireFTP but I only get '530 Login authentication failed'

Comment: This discussion is getting to extensive. Try to google. The error you get speaks for itself. You probaly gave the wrong username and/or password. There are plenty of topics out there that give you awnsers on how to `cmod` files using the command line.

Answer (score 0):

In your browser you have a tool called *inspector*. You can open it with `F12` and there (usually in `Network` tab) you can see all the requests your web page makes.

With the inspector I can see that your server is giving `Error 403 Forbidden` on these images.

I suggest you to check the permissions of the images on the server.

Comment: ok. thanks. I'll try to see see if I can manage to change the permissions